# How to change the color pattern of codes (echo = True) in an Rmarkdown file?

Tags: colors, r-markdown, themes, echo

I'm generating a Rmarkdown file, showing the script (echo = TRUE) in the report. The code is shown in a color pattern, like in this image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAxON.png), with some in blue, some green, and some black. How can I choose a different color pattern? The green color looks not very readable. I would really appreciate any help! Thanks so much!

I tried changing the R preference - editor theme, but this does not change the color pattern in the knitted file. As this is not using the methods of color specification for plain text, I have no idea how to change this color pattern for reported codes themselves.

Comment: Check [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style).

Answer (score 1):

You have different highlighting styles, I found [this gallery](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/pandoc-syntax-highlighting-examples/).

```
output:
    html_document:
        highlight: zenburn
```

On [bookdown.org](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/appearance-and-style-1.html)
`highlight` specifies the syntax highlighting style. Supported styles include `"default"`, `"tango"`, `"pygments"`, `"kate"`, `"monochrome"`, `"espresso"`, `"zenburn"`, and `"haddock"`. Pass null to prevent syntax highlighting.

Alternatively, you can look at different themes for the entire document, they come with different colour palettes for the output of source code.

- https://prettydoc.statr.me/themes.html
- https://github.com/juba/rmdformats

Looking into [code decoration](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-decoration) guidelines, I don't see a way to easily pick your own colours.

For default themes:

```
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: Harry Potter
date: July 31, 2016
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
```

To add a prettydoc theme, install the prettydoc package, just type the one you chose at the top of your document, as explained on the prettydoc home page.

```
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: Harry Potter
date: July 31, 2016
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
```